# Google oauth blocked in local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm playing around with omniauth in a rails/ember app, and I'm hitting a bit of a wall with google sign in. I get presented the pop-up to allow the site to authenticate me, but after clicking accept the request bombs out:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:3001" from 
accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com". Protocols, domains, 
and ports must match.
```

I'm using a self-signed cert to get HTTPS in local development, but how do I test this auth logic locally?

Coffeescript attempting to do the sign in:

```
$ ->
  $.ajax
    url: '//apis.google.com/js/client:plus.js?onload=gpAsyncInit'
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true
window.gpAsyncInit = ->
  $(".google-login").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    gapi.auth.authorize
      immediate: false
      response_type: "code"
      client_id: "<%= ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"] %>"
      scope: "email profile"
    , (response) ->
      if response and not response.error
        jQuery.ajax
          type: "POST"
          url: "/auth/google_oauth2/callback"
          dataType: "json"
          data: response
          success: (json) ->
            alert 'success!'
      else
        alert response.error
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing localhost with a valid domain, eg. mydevserver.me.com. You can point mydevserver.me.com to 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts. You will also need to add http://mydevserver.me.com/mycallback as a callback url to the Google API console